# How to mass-deploy a root certificate in a corporate environment

Tags: keychain, certificate, enterprise

Our Windows administrator deploys a root CA certificate to all the machines through [Group Policies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy), which works very well in a corporate setting. Is there something similar to this we can use for our Apple devices? Currently we are manually installing the root certificate on every Mac machine when there is an update or we purchase a new machine.

Comment: Do you use a MDM solution in your organization? It should be possible to automatically deploy root certificate using any one of the various MDM solutions.

Comment: @NimeshNeema You mean [master data management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_data_management)? I'm not familiar with that but I don't think we have that right now.

Comment: I am talking about [Mobile Device Management](https://help.apple.com/deployment/macos/#/ior07301dd60)

Comment: We use JAMF for our Mac and iPad MDM, and it is capable of deploying root certificates. There are other MDM systems available which can do this.